# Side lengths of a triangle satisfy $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that $3≤a+b+c≤2√3$

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, triangles, geometric-inequalities

> The lengths $a,b$ and $c$ are the side lengths of a triangle that satisfy $ab+bc+ca=3$. Prove that $3≤a+b+c≤2√3$

I was able to find the minimum bound through some simple algebra:

$a+b+c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2+6}$

But, $a^2+b^2+c^2≥ab+bc+ca=3$

$\implies a+b+c≥\sqrt{3+6}$
$$3≤a+b+c$$

Alternatively we could use AM GM on $ab+bc+ca$ and then on $a^2+b^2+c^2$

After this I couldn't think of how to use the triangle inequality in conjunction with the given condition $ab+bc+ca=3$ to get an upper bound on the sum, any help would be appreciated, thanks